# how to sort array of files alphabetically based on a specific line in each file

Tags: php, arrays, sorting, foreach

i have a lot of `txt` files in which i stored plain data.
All txt files are stored in `data/articles` directory.
A txt file looks like this:

```
id_20200430223049                     // id line
friends                               // category line
uploads/mainimage_5eab357970b0d.jpeg  // image line
officials wanted                      // title line
comment<br />comment<br />comment     // message line
30 apr 2020 22:30                     // date line
jack                                  // author line
```

To output all the title-anchors from the files, i use this code:

```
$blogfiles = glob("data/articles/*.txt"); // Specify the file directory by extension (.txt)

foreach($blogfiles as $blogfile){

    $lines = file($blogfile, FILE_IGNORE_NEW_LINES); // filedata into an array  
    $blog_id =  $lines[0]; //  blog id                                      
    $blog_title = $lines[3]; //  blog title 
    ?>              

    <a href="admin.php?page=<?php echo $blog_id; ?>"><?php echo $blog_title; ?></a><br />
<?php                   
} // end foreach                    
?>
```

In this case, all the links are not alphabetically sorted on the **titles**!

For sorting all **titles** i created a new array:

```
$handle = @fopen($blogfile, "r");                                               
if ($handle) {

    $lines = file($blogfile, FILE_IGNORE_NEW_LINES); // file in to an array
    $title_line = $lines[3];

    if(strpos(strtolower($title_line)) !== FALSE) { // strtolower; category word not case sensitive 

        $title_lines[] = $title_line;                                                           
    }
    fclose($handle);
}
sort($title_lines);
print_r($title_lines); // now the titles are sorted!
```

But how can i output all the anchors with the **sorted titles**???

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This code builds an array based on the first code you have, but adds each entry into an array, indexed by the blog_id and the title as the value.  Then use `uasort()` to sort whilst retaining the keys and `strcasecmp()` to do a case insensitive sort.  You can then output this array for your links...

```
$blog_data = [];
foreach($blogfiles as $blogfile){
    $lines = file($blogfile, FILE_IGNORE_NEW_LINES); // filedata into an array
    $blog_data [$lines[0]] = $lines[3];
} // end foreach  

uasort($blog_data, 'strcasecmp');  // Sort case insensitive

foreach ( $blog_data as $blog_id => $blog_title ) {   ?>
    <a href="admin.php?page=<?php echo $blog_id; ?>"><?php echo $blog_title; ?></a><br />
<?php  
}
```